# IE8 Anchor href taking precedence over onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have the following link running fine in all browsers except IE8.  Does the code in the href override the onclick attribute? In IE8, the href gets executed but the onlick does not. Can anyone help?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" type="submit" onclick="$('#loginForm').submit();">Log in</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use something like this?

```
<a href="#" id="example>Log in</a>
```

Then using javascript (with the jQuery library)

```
$("#example").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the href from jumping to the top
  $('#loginForm').submit(); //Submit the form

});
```

The reason i suggest this is because using inline JavaScript is not good practice.
Have a read here to see why -> http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: Says "using javascript"... uses jQuery.

Comment: +1 - adding a real href value would be kinder ( or attaching the onclick to the submit button )

Comment: @Kolink, jQuery is JavaScript. Its like says you driving a car not a vehicle.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko jQuery !== JavaScript. jQuery takes a perfectly good building, demolishes it, then sells itself by picking stuff out of the rubble for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error console (F12 => Console) for errors.

`href` is "called" after `onClick`, unless the event has `return false;` or otherwise prevents the default action.